# Why do I get undefined output vectors and an undefined clock when simulating?

Tags: vector, vhdl, test-bench

I am pretty new to VHDL and am encountering an error with my testbench (at least I believe its only in the testbench).
My programme simulates a stadium with 12 sections. The programme consists of 12 individual counters along with LEDs when 90% of max capacity is reached and a digital 4 digit display that displays the total of all 12 counters.

Whenever I try to compile the code, there is no change in any of the outputs and all of the inputs are undefined.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Architecture:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.Numeric_STD.all;

entity counter is

Port (Clk: in STD_LOGIC;
      Enable : in STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0);
      Reset : in STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0);
      Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12 : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(8 downto 0); -- 9 bits as 300 <2^9
      Qt : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0); -- 12 bits as 300 (section) * 12 > 2^12
      a,b,c,d,e,f,g : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(3 downto 0); --Individual segments of the display (4 because the number will max out at 3600)
      Led0,Led1,Led2,Led3,Led4,Led5,Led6,Led7,Led8,Led9,Led10,Led11 : out STD_LOGIC);
end counter;      
      

Architecture behavioral of counter is
    
    type REG_variable is array(0 to 11) of unsigned(8 downto 0);
    type Q_variable is array (0 to 11) of STD_LOGIC_Vector(8 downto 0);
    type DIGITS_variable is array (0 to 3) of unsigned (3 downto 0);
    
    signal output_array : Q_variable;
    signal LED_Output : STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0);
    
    
    component count_comp is
        Port(Clk, Reset, Enable : in STD_Logic;
        Q : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(8 downto 0);
        LED : out STD_LOGIC);
    end component; 
    
begin 
    process (CLK,Reset)
        variable LED_lights : STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable REG : REG_variable := (others =>(others => '0'));
        variable Total_REG: unsigned(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable Digits : DIGITS_variable := (others => (others => '0'));
    
begin 
Single_Counter : for i in 11 downto 0 loop
   if Reset(i) = '1' then
   Total_REG := Total_REG - REG(i);
   REG(i) := (others => '0');
   LED_lights(i) := '0';
       elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
             if Enable(i) = '1' and (REG(i) <= 300) then
             if (REG(i) >= 270) then
                  LED_lights(i) := '1';
                  Total_REG := Total_REG + 1;
                  REG(i) := REG(i)+ 1;
             end if;   
         
Digits(0) := to_unsigned(to_integer(Total_REG - Total_REG mod 100),4);
Digits(1) := to_unsigned(to_integer((Total_REG - Total_REG mod 100)/10),4);
Digits(2) := to_unsigned(to_integer((Total_REG - Total_REG mod 100)/100),4);
Digits(3) := to_unsigned(to_integer((Total_REG - Total_REG mod 100)/1000),4);

end if;
end if;

Qt <= STD_LOGIC_Vector(Total_REG);
output_array(i) <= STD_LOGIC_Vector(REG(i));
LED_output(i) <= LED_lights(i);


for x in 3 downto 0 loop
case to_integer(Digits(x)) is

    when 0
    => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '1'; f(x) <= '1'; g(x) <= '0';
     
    when 1
    => a(x) <= '0'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '0'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '0'; g(x) <= '0';
    
    when 2 
    => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '0'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '1'; f(x) <= '0'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when 3 
    => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '0'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when 4
    => a(x) <= '0'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '0'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '1'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when 5
     => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '0'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '1'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when 6 
    => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '0'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '1'; f(x) <= '1'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when 7 
    => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '0'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '0'; g(x) <= '0';
    
    when 8
     => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '1'; f(x) <= '1'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when 9
    => a(x) <= '1'; b(x) <= '1'; c(x) <= '1'; d(x) <= '1'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '1'; g(x) <= '1';
    
    when others
    => a(x) <= '0'; b(x) <= '0'; c(x) <= '0'; d(x) <= '0'; e(x) <= '0'; f(x) <= '0'; g(x) <= '0';
    
   end case; 
   end loop;
end loop;   
end process;

Counters : for i in 11 downto 0 generate
   counter_gen : count_comp
   port map (CLK => CLK, Reset => Reset (i), Enable => Enable(i), Q => output_array(i), LED => LED_output(i));
end generate;
    
Q1 <= output_array(0);
Q2 <= output_array(1);
Q3 <= output_array(2);
Q4 <= output_array(3);
Q5 <= output_array(4);
Q6 <= output_array(5);
Q7 <= output_array(6);
Q8 <= output_array(7);
Q9 <= output_array(8);
Q10 <= output_array(9);
Q11 <= output_array(10);
Q12 <= output_array(11);

Led0 <= LED_output(0);
Led1 <= LED_output(1);
Led2 <= LED_output(2);
Led3 <= LED_output(3);
Led4 <= LED_output(4);
Led5 <= LED_output(5);
Led6 <= LED_output(6);
Led7 <= LED_output(7);
Led8 <= LED_output(8);
Led9 <= LED_output(9);
Led10 <= LED_output(10);
Led11 <= LED_output(11);

end behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Project_Testbench is
end;
 
architecture TB1 of Project_Testbench is
 
       component count_comp is
      Port(Clk: in STD_LOGIC;
         Enable : in STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0);
         Reset : in STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0);
         Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12 : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(8 downto 0);
         Qt : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(11 downto 0);
         a,b,c,d,e,f,g : out STD_LOGIC_Vector(3 downto 0);
         Led0,Led1,Led2,Led3,Led4,Led5,Led6,Led7,Led8,Led9,Led10,Led11 : out STD_LOGIC);
    end component count_comp; 
     
     signal Clk_TB : std_logic := '0';
     signal Enable : std_logic_Vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
     signal Reset : std_logic_Vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin 

     Clk_TB <= not Clk_TB after 5ns;

    
stimuli: process
     
        begin

         Enable <= "000000000000"; Reset <= "11111111111";
         wait for 100 ns;
         
         Enable <= "11111111111"; Reset <= "00000000000";
         wait for 200 ns;
         
         Enable <= "11110011111"; Reset <= "00000000000";
         wait for 50 ns;
         
         Enable <= "00011111111"; Reset <= "00000000000";
         wait for 20 ns;
         
         Enable <= "11111111111"; Reset <= "11000000000";
         wait for 20 ns;
         
         Enable <= "11111111111"; Reset <= "00000000000";
         wait for 1000 ns;

        
        wait;
        
        end process;

uut: count_comp port map
    (
     Clk => Clk_TB,
     Enable => Enable,
     Reset => Reset);
      
 
     
end;
```

Here is a screenshot of the output signals.
[Output Signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rGwJ.png)

Comment: Do you mean "Whenever I try to <strikethrough>compile</strikethrough> simulate the code, there is no change in any of the outputs and all of the inputs are undefined."

Comment: You don't provide the entity and architecture for component comp. You problem may be duplicated for the wrong reasons. Provide a [mcve]. There are 11 semantic errors and 1 lexical error (5ns, "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal."). The semantic errors are string literal lengths not matching the subtype length of Enable and Reset in process stimuli (they're all 1 short except the first one).

Comment: Your waveform may indicate you're trying to simulate something else beside the testbench. Note Clk, Enable and Reset are all shown in orange as 'U's.

Comment: You appear to instantiate count_comp in the testbench when you probably mean to instantiate counter. (Fixing the errors alluded to in the previous comments shows comp_count doesn't have led associations.) Fixing the component declaration to be for counter and changing the component name to counter in the instantiation allows the testbench to be elaborated (the testbench can be simulated).

Comment: That has fixed it now thanks. The inputs are now displaying (the outputs aren't but I think I can fix that myself.)